# Is there a way to exclude certain subcategories when googling site:?

Tags: google-search

I sincerely apologize for not being able to articulate the question any better than this.

I want to grab copy from a customers website and create a shared Docs including the copy, while HTTrack and other more fancy methods would be preferable for me, it doesn't suit the customer relation.

So.

I want to

```
site:stackoverflow.com
```

and then add arguments that exclude /brands/ for example.

**Is that possible?**

I really have tried to search for the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I had a coworker figure this one out for me.

What I was looking for was

```
site:stackoverflow.com -inurl:brands
```

that would've solved the example I posed.